# Images are not shown in Odoo v9.0

Tags: image, odoo, odoo-website

I was evaluating Odoo v9.0 by pulling odoo v9.0 branch in my system and found that it is having some problem in showing the images. It prompts up with an error "Could not display the selected Image". If you open the product form view or company form view it comes up with the error. Even if you try to save new image to a product, after saving the image again it comes with the same error and image is not displayed.

The same issue is with the odoo e-commerce website, where no images are seen. I tried to debug where I can see that binary value is found, but somehow not been displayed on the screen.

Does it require any configuration? Does anybody knows the reason for this?

Comment: May you please give some information or link for Odoo v9.0 where you that pulling from?

Comment: Have you done modification anything.? Or is it from the current repo.? If you have not modified anything in repo then I think you should post on GitHub.com/odoo/odoo/issues

Comment: @Odedra I used  git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo -b 9.0 . Let me know if you need anything more

Comment: @010100100110111101101110011 I have not made any changes. I used git clone github.com/odoo/odoo -b 9.0 few days back. The thing is when I look into runboot for the same branch, it does show the image, so I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: @HardikPatadia I think You need to update your repo. How old it is.? The reason is there is a big change in Image mechanism see here https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/5a6e136172c14dd7340f3f073c00fdf8b0ce4a2c and here https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/5232fb9e24ee8be9fc90bb6b8aae03e2cfacfc8f So can you try after updating .? May be it will get resolved. and dont go to master branch as it is not updated since20 days. ;)

Comment: @HardikPatadia, I update with 9.0 and master branch and run server, my Odoo 9 looking wired, everything overlapping each-other, (images, content, Admin links) very disappointments from the new changes.

Comment: @010100100110111101101110011 I will try to update it and check it out.

Comment: @Odedra are you working on old DB, can you create with new one. Its working superb here.

Comment: @010100100110111101101110011, what is your git last commit id? Mine git last commit id is 5209bb255decb24479a1995bd5b1eb4423d199e3 and i also create a new db, db create successfully but module image (kanbanview) overlapping eachother. I will post it later.

Comment: @Odedra where did you find this commit information?

Comment: @Odedra, Ya thats an current issue in odoo9 You can post it on github.

Comment: for checking history of commit you can type this command. *git log*

Comment: thank you @Odedra ... even I have the same last commit.

Comment: JFI, I report issue on github https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/8824 if you want than you  may write your commit.

Comment: @Odedra are you having the "lessc" installed on your system? because this thing doesn't happen at my side.

Comment: @010100100110111101101110011 I pulled latest code, created new db.. but the situation is same, don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: @HardikPatadia, Yes i have complete with all required all installation dependency but still have screen resolution problem.

Comment: @Odedra can you tell me which ubuntu/linux flavour you are using? Because, change in version or flavour may required appropriate less version.

Comment: @HardikPatadia, I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

You have to update your `werkzeug` python library.

```
pip install --upgrade werkzeug
```

Comment: I think you are right, when I debug and reached in depth, I found that there is a file under this library called "serving.py", which is causing the problem, so even I thought that we need to update the lib. Thanks for the reply !!.

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
sudo pip install --upgrade werkzeug
```