# Odoo 9 Could not display Selected Image

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I install **odoo9** latest build from **nightly** on **ubuntu 15.04**

For customer object or any other image field if i upload image odoo9 display warning popup `Could not display the selected Image`. I don't understand whats wrong ?

[image]

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Duplicate Q. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880329/images-are-not-shown-in-odoo-v9-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command

```
sudo pip install --upgrade werkzeug
```

Answer (score 0):

apply this command in terminal

image break  in local

```
sudo pip install werkzeug --upgrade
```

Comment: I have same problem please tell me about solution there `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987347/could-not-display-selected-image-in-odoo-9` if you found it.. I'll be very thankful...