# Could not display Selected Image in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

I have problem with image loading in `product.template` form view. When i upload a new image it is uploading and `displaying correctly` in `product kanban view`, but in `product form view` it is giving me error ***Could not display Selected Image*** as displaying in attached image

[image]

Someone please tell me about why it is happening. I'll be very thankful ..

Comment: Someone please help me about this matter ...

Comment: please update your branch or get the pull from odoo8 and odoo9

Comment: can you please guide me, how can i update branch???

Comment: update latest code from git: https://github.com/odoo/odoo

Comment: It is giving me this error..`
web/image?model=product.template&id=3&field=image_medi                                                                             um&unique=20160627045230 HTTP/1.1" 500`

Comment: all remove the catch from browser and check with new database and start sever with -u all

Comment: can you provide me any screenshot and detail about what you do ?