# HIde delete button from export data form view in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

I want to `hide` `delete button` from ***Export Data form view*** in odoo. Button that i want to hide also highlighted in attached image.

[image]

I'll be very thankful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override Odoo's QWeb templates for such customizations.

Create a xml under mymodule/static/src/xml (e.g. your_customization.xml) with following content:

```xml
<template>
    <t t-extend="Exists.ExportList">
        <t t-jquery="button[id|='delete_export_list']" t-operation="replace" />
    </t>
</template>
```

And then don't forget to call that file in your manifest (__openerp__.py) like

```py
{
    # other things like author, name, data
    'qweb': ['static/src/xml/your_customization.xml'],
}
```

Comment: can you please answer it `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987347/could-not-display-selected-image-in-odoo-9`

Comment: Sorry, but i have no answer for that question.